# I do not understand the error. Is there a limit to the number variables in \foreach?

Tags: tables, foreach

It always issues an error if I use \markthree in the last row, see below. The error is

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> {
> l.60 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up` weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

{
l.60 }

```
{Personal Total $=$ Personal mark $+$ Group total mark \vskip1mm [20]} &\pgfmathparse{\markone+\groupmark}\pgfmathresult &\pgfmathparse{\marktwo+\groupmark}\pgfmathprint{\pgfmathresult} &\pgfmathparse{\groupmark+\markthree}\pgfmathprint{\pgfmathresult} \\[5mm]
```

If I delete `\markthree` in this line, it works fine. I do not understand what the issue is. Is it because there is a limit to the number of variables used in the `\foreach` command?

```
\documentclass[multi=true,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,calc,}
%opening
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture, frame}
\date{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
    
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \node (1) {};
    \foreach \groupnum/\grouptitle/\feedback/\groupmark/\pone/\markone/\ptwo/\marktwo/\pthree/\markthree in {
        1/title1/
            {feedbackone}
            /{11}/name1/{5}/name2/{5}/name3/{4},
        6/{}/{}/{0}/name1/{}/name2/{}/{}/{}
    }{
%   \node (\groupnum)[below=10 mm of current bounding box]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (title) [below=10mm of current bounding box, text width = 18cm, align = flush center, font=\Large\bfseries]{marking proforma};    
\node (table) [below=5mm of title, text width = 25cm]{  
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{5cm} |m{6cm} |m{6cm} |m{6cm}|}
    \toprule
    \hline  
    Group Number: & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries\groupnum}\\
    \hline
    Presentation title: & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\large\textbf{\color{blue}\grouptitle}}\\
    \hline


        Feedback & \multicolumn{3}{p{18cm}|}{\feedback}\\[5cm]
    \hline
    Group Total [15]&  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\groupmark}\\[5mm]
    \hline
        Presenter & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries\pone}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries\ptwo} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries\pthree} \\
    \hline
    Presenter personal mark ([5])&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\markone}  &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\marktwo}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\markthree}\\[5mm]
    \hline
    {Personal Total $=$ Personal mark $+$ Group total mark \vskip1mm [20]} &\pgfmathparse{\markone+\groupmark}\pgfmathresult &\pgfmathparse{\marktwo+\groupmark}\pgfmathprint{\pgfmathresult} &\pgfmathparse{\groupmark+\markthree}\pgfmathprint{\pgfmathresult} \\[5mm]
    \hline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem with using 10 variables. The issue is `\pgfmathparse{\groupmark+\markthree}` receiving `{}` instead of a number.

With the following changes your code compiles fine:

```
\foreach \groupnum/\grouptitle/\feedback/\groupmark/\pone/\markone/\ptwo/\marktwo/\pthree/\markthree in {
    1/title1/
        {feedbackone}
        /{11}/name1/{5}/name2/{5}/name3/{4},
    6/{}/{}/{0}/name1/{}/name2/{}/{}/0 % <-- Notice change here
}{
```